# How to read a specific line from the file and register it as a variable and pass it to another role in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am creating a azure image using ansible roles, below is the sample of my play book:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  roles: 
   - azure_vmcreator

- hosts: azure_vms
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - vm_software
    - download_Artifact

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  roles: 
    - azure_imagecreator
```

The idea is to download a f.exe file in download_Artifact role and install it in the vm, on installation f.exe will create a product.id file. I want to read the second line of that file and register it as a variable say image_prefix, so that i can use image_prefix variable in azure_imagecreator role and create a image adding it in the prefix.

I am new to ansible can any one help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing variables set on another host in a playbook isn't very straightforward. The general workflow would look like this:

In `download_Artifact` use the `set_fact` module to save the line in question as a `host_var`. ( `set_fact` always stores variables as host vars).

You can use `with_file` to get the contents of a file into a variable and then use jinja to get the second line of the file:

```
    - name: Print Second line of a File
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.split("\n")[1] }}"
      with_file:
        - "/filepath"
```

What the jinja2 snippet does, is splitting the file on newlines, converting it to an array of the lines, and then accessing the second line (Array indices start with 0).

Instead of printing the contents, you would need to use the `set_fact` module to save that string into a variable.

Then, In your third playbook, pass the hostvar you've set as an argument to the role. Use can use `hostvars.<hostname>.<varname>` to access the hostvars of another host.

If you don't know the hostname beforehand, you can use ansibles special variable `groups` to get the name during playbook execution. The call would then look somewhat like this (haven't tested this though and assuming your role accepts a variable called `image_prefix`):

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  roles: 
    - name: azure_imagecreator
      azure_imagecreator:
        image_prefix: hostvars[groups.azure_vms[0]].image_prefix
```

Comment: Who should i read a line from a file and send it to a variable ?

Comment: @VinayUpadhyay I've updated to answer to show you how to get the contents of the file.